# inserting an element in to a std::set causes several errors

Tags: c++, set

Consider the following class

```
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
class foo {
public:
  struct spatial {
    bool block;
    char status;  // H, M, Z
  };

  typedef pair< int, vector<spatial> > way;  // tag + spatial vector
  typedef set< way > one_set;


  void bar() 
  {
     way theWay;
     theWay.first = 10;

     one_set theSet;
     one_set::iterator sit = theSet.end();
     if (theSet.size() == 16) {
        sit = theSet.begin();
     }
     theSet.insert(sit, theWay);
  }
};
```

For the insert function, I receive these errors and I don't know what does that mean

```
error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &,const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::vector<_Ty,_Ax> &' from 'const foo::spatial'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility

error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Tree<_Traits> &,const std::_Tree<_Traits> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Tree<_Traits> &' from 'const foo::spatial'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility 3144

error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &,const std::unique_ptr<_Ty2,_Dx2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,_Dx> &' from 'const foo::spatial'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility 3144

error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::reverse_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'const foo::spatial'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility 3144

error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &,const std::_Revranit<_RanIt2,_Base2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::_Revranit<_RanIt,_Base> &' from 'const foo::spatial'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility 3144    

error C2784: 'bool std::operator <(const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &,const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &' from 'const foo::spatial'    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility 3144

error C2676: binary '<' : 'const foo::spatial' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xutility 3144
```

Stuck at this point. Appreciate any help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your `way` type must have an `operator<` defined to be used in an `std::set`.

`std::pair` has `operator<` if both types has `operator<`. `int` has `operator<`, that is ok, but `vector<spatial>` has `operator<` only if its element type has `operator<`. Your `spatial` class has none and therefore your `way` typedef has no `operator<` as well.

Create an `operator<` for your `spatial` class and you're ok.

If you think that `spatial` classes should not be comparable but insist on having `way` in a set, you can also create your own comparator (a functor/lambda with two `const way&` parameters that return `true` if the first is less than the second) and pass that as the second template parameter of your set.

Anyway, because `std::set` stores its elements sorted, to use it you have to define the ordering of your elements at some point.

Comment: how can I overload < to sort on the first element of way? comparing the vectors are meaningless in this context.

Comment: What about `unordered_set`? error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from 'const foo::way' to 'size_t' c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xfunctional 768

Comment: For `unordered_set` you have to create a hash function for your `way` type. (Hash functions are not automatic even for `pair`s)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your use-case you can also use `unordered_set`.  There you need a `operator==` and a hash-function:

```
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
  struct spatial {
    bool block;
    char status;  // H, M, Z

    bool operator== (spatial const & that) const {
       return block==that.block && status==that.status;
    }

    size_t hash() const {
       return status & static_cast<int>(block) << 9;
    }
  };

  typedef pair< int, vector<spatial> > way;  // tag + spatial vector

  struct way_hash {
    size_t operator()(const way &w) const{
      return w.first;
    }
  };

  typedef unordered_set< way, foo::way_hash > one_set;

  void bar() 
  {
     way theWay;
     theWay.first = 10;

     one_set theSet;
     one_set::iterator sit = theSet.end();
     if (theSet.size() == 16) {
        sit = theSet.begin();
     }
     theSet.insert(sit, theWay);
  }
};

int main() {
   foo f;
   f.bar();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your code does not compile. You'll also need a hash function for `way`.

Comment: You are completely right: I did only a compile-check the first time, without linking.